# Does anybody knos how to download pycario?

Tags: pycairo

Hi I am middle school student and trying to download something called Pycario, in order to use  manim for my math project. However, I am facing some problems.

I have downloaded python3.9.0, and downloaded .whl file named pycairo‑1.20.1‑cp310‑cp310‑win32.whl( my computer is not-amd, and 64bit)

Then, I tiped in cmd:
**pip install pycairo-1.20.1-cp39-cp39-win32**

I expected successful download, but instead I got:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycairo-1.20.1-cp39-cp39-win32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycairo-1.20.1-cp39-cp39-win32**

I am sure that I downloaded the correct .whl file, but I can not download pycario and do not know why.

I know literally nothing about programming, somebody pls help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `.whl` in the filename.

```
pip install pycairo-1.20.1-cp39-cp39-win32.whl
```